# Maven multimodule dependency not found

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am getting a quite odd error that I can't seem to explain.

I have a multimodule maven project where I've built a module that tests the integration between two other modules.

So pretty much something like this:

```
root
|
+--dispatcher
|
+--worker
|
+--tester
```

and if I run the tester with IntelliJ everything is fine, however running it through maven fails.
And it fails because it cannot find a specific package, not because it cannot find the artifact.

I have tried creating a new project to test the concept behind module dependencies and it seems to work, but I cannot seem to find why.

So these are the pom files:

Parent:

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>se.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>parentid</artifactId>
  <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <description>Parent project for all maven modules.</description>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>

  <modules>
    <module>worker</module>
    <module>dispatcher</module>
    <module>service-testing</module>
  </modules>
...
</project>
```

Dispatcher:

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <artifactId>dispatcher</artifactId>
  <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>dispatcher</name>

  <parent>
    <groupId>se.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>parentid</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.version>${project.version}</project.version>
  </properties>

  <scm>
    <developerConnection>
      scm:git:https://ghe.com/dispatcher.git
    </developerConnection>
    <connection>scm:git:https://ghe.com/dispatcher.git
    </connection>
    <url>https://ghe.com/dispatcher</url>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
  </scm>

  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>releases</id>
      <url>http://nexus.net/repository/maven-releases</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <url>http://nexus.net/repository/maven-snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>
...
</project>
```

And tester:

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <artifactId>systemtest</artifactId>
  <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>systemtest</name>

  <parent>
    <groupId>se.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>parentid</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.version>${project.version}</project.version>
  </properties>

  <scm>
    <developerConnection>
      scm:git:https://ghe.com/dispatcher.git
    </developerConnection>
    <connection>scm:git:https://ghe.com/dispatcher.git
    </connection>
    <url>https://ghe.com/dispatcher</url>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
  </scm>

  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>releases</id>
      <url>http://nexus.net/repository/maven-releases</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <url>http://nexus.net/repository/maven-snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>se.group</groupId>
      <artifactId>dispatcher</artifactId>
      <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
...
</project>
```

This should work right?

Ok, this is kind of odd I think.
If I run `mvn clean install` it breaks, but it seems as if it works if I run `mvn clean package install`

Comment: Did you define the dependencies between the modules correctly?

Comment: well the dependency is defined in the pom for the tester as written in the question. I assume that this is correct?

Comment: please verify if this package exists somewhere after `mvn clean` and then after `mvn package`.